# Feather a plane edge which is used as shadow catcher

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I am using a plane right below my 3D model as a shadow catcher using Cycles rendering engine.

The plane is casting the shadow perfectly but as you can see on the attached screenshot the plane edges while casting the shadow is too hard. Is there a way to soften the edges? I guess I can not really use transparency on the material since I am using the for Shadow Catcher for the plane.

[image]

Render Engine: Cycles
I have enabled *Transparency* under *Film > Render Settings*.
The plane has the Shadow Catcher enabled under *Visibility > Object Properties*.

Comment: Can't you just scale up the circle to catch all of the cube's shadow? Or if you later use compositing to put the cube on top of a cylinder for example, a hard cut-off shadow makes sense, and you don't need to feather it.

Comment: I guess the problem is, especially with people later coming to this question because they explicitly **want** a feathered shadow (what I guess the OP wants too), answers like scaling it larger or a hard cut-off makes sense won't help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve a soft or feathered border on your *Shadow Catcher* object you have to setup a material for it with transparency which increases to the edge. Here is an example how you can do it, first I created a circular gradient from center to edge, there are multiple ways to get it, but anyway. The important thing is, you have to mix the *Transparent* shader with another one like *Diffuse* for example, if not the *Shadow Catcher* will be completely transparent and not show any shadow.

This is the node setup, the rendered preview doesn't look perfect but once you hit <kbd>F12</kbd> it will render correctly:

[image: shadowcatcher setup]

Rendered version:

[image: shadow catcher render]

This is how the mix factor for *Diffuse* and *Transparent* looks like:

[image: shadow mix factor]

EDIT: Just a short addition. If you simply just enable *Shadow Catcher* on an object, it usually still effects the scene via light bounces or maybe reflections - which might be what you want. To show what I mean, in the image below on the left side you can see the red light bounce on the cube (I've set the *Diffuse Shader* to a red color to make it obvious). If you don't want the *Shadow Catcher* object to effect the scene, you turn off everything under *Ray Visibility* except for *Camera*, so there will be no interaction with other objects (see on the right side).

[image: shadow catcher disabled]

Comment: I could finally set up all the nodes but unfortunately, I could not get the same result as you did here. Do I have to enable the Shadow catcher in the object properties? Either way, it doesn't work. Here is the screenshot.
https://i.postimg.cc/ryBXNjb2/Screenshot-2021-10-18-at-15-32-33.png

Comment: Of course you have to enable _Shadow Catcher_. The difference I can see in your node setup is that in the _Distance_ node you're calculating the distance to 0/0/0, but with the _Generated_ texture coordinates you have to use 0.5/0.5/0.5, but actually you can use anything that creates a gradient like the one in my last screenshot.

Comment: Sorry if the _Shadow Catcher_ part was unclear, I'll edit my answer. This was a material for the _Shadow Catcher_, not instead of a _Shadow Catcher_.

Comment: Yeees, it worked. oh man, you are a blender guru. A lot of respect and gratitude.

Comment: @AshkanSharifi I've made an addition at the end of my answer.

Comment: If anyone can't find the "Distance" node in the screenshot of the Shader editor, you need the "Vector Math" node, then set it to "Distance"

Comment: @tomh Yes, right - thanks for the addition. I just mentioned in the question I used a circular gradient - basically there are many different ways to get that. A simple image texture with a gradient, the _Gradient Texture_ node set to "Quadratic Sphere" or "Spherical", the _Vector Math_ node set to "Distance" but you could also set it to "Length"... and maybe even more possible things to achieve this. You don't even have to use a circular gradient, it depends on what result you want.